# php preg_match How to

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to get a "ref code" from the html but just the "ref" when label is P

Ex: 031-0132-806-02

How can I do this using preg_match???

How can I get this information with preg_match?

```
{
label: 'P',
available: false, 
ref: '031-0132-806-02'
},
{
label: 'M',
available: false, 
ref: '031-0132-806-03'
}] 
} 
},
```

Comment: Why not decode the data with `json_decode()` first, then process the object/array to get the info you want?

Comment: Is that code an object or do you want to regex on exactly that code?

Comment: Yes... there a json inside de html. It start with productPage1.init({ and finish with //]]> </script>. Is there a way to get using preg_math ?

Comment: The reference URL is www.netshoes.com.br/produto/031-0132-172-02 . Check the source code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a foreach loop:

```
$string = <<<WUT
{
label: 'P',
available: false, 
ref: '031-0132-806-02'
},
{
label: 'M',
available: false, 
ref: '031-0132-806-03'
}] 
} 
},
WUT;

$ref = array();

preg_match_all('/(?P<labels>{\s*label:.*?})/s', $string, $m);

foreach($m['labels'] as $code){
    if(strpos($code, "label: 'P'")){
        preg_match('/ref: \'(.*?)\'/', $code, $n);
        $ref[] = $n[1];
    }
}

print_r($ref);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the numbers are always in the same pattern you can do it with this:

```
<?php
    $string = "{
    label: 'P',
    available: false, 
    ref: '031-0132-806-02'
    },
    {
    label: 'M',
    available: false, 
    ref: '031-0132-806-03'
    }] 
    } 
    },";

    preg_match_all('![0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2}!',$string,$matches);

    print_r($matches);

?>
```

**Updated** Let's say this is a crawler for the data.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.urltocapture...';

function crawlSite($url){
    $refIDs = array();
        $string = file_get_contents($url);

        preg_match_all('!\items: +?\[[^]]+\]!s',$string,$sets);
        foreach($sets as $items){
            foreach($items as $item){

                $cleanupPattern = array('!\t+!','! +!','!(\r\n|\n|\r)+!','! +!');
                $cleanupReplacements = array(' ',' ',""," ",);
              $item = preg_replace($cleanupPattern,$cleanupReplacements,$item);
              //echo $item."\n";    

            preg_match_all('!label: \'P\'[^\}]+([0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2})[^\}]+}!',$item,$item_match);

                if(!empty($item_match[1][0])){
                    $refIDs[] = $item_match[1][0];
                }
            }
        }
        return $refIDs;

}

$refIDs = crawlSite($url);
print_r($refIDs);

?>
```

Comment: Ok nice.. but how can I get only "ref" when "label" is 'P' ? This string is a part of json inside the html. There is a way to get the json using preg_match and use json_decode()? The URL referente is www.netshoes.com.br/produto/031-0132-172-02

Comment: Is this your site (access to the original json) or are you mining it?